# Linq Relationship Connections

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am using entity framework, and require a way of making a collection available using linq. I'll show what I mean.

I have 3 tables.

- Products
- ProductOptions
- Product_ProductOption_Mappings

I am using the `Product_ProductOption_Mappings` table to create a many-to-many relationship between `Product` and `ProductOptions`. Given a specific product, I would like to pull out a collection of it's product options.

```
using((Model.Entities context = new Model.Entities())
{
    var options = context.Products
            .Where(p => p.ID == 1)
            .First()
            .Product_ProductOption_Mappings.ProductOptions.ToList();
}
```

Now this isn't correct, but it is intended to return a list of `ProductOptions` that are 'realted' to the `Products`.

Any help would be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your many to many table only contains the two Ids necessary for the management of the relationship EF should support hiding that linking table from your conceptual model.  Basically you should just have a Product and ProductOption entity in your conceptual model with a Many-to-Many association between them.  In the example below I have named the navigation property contained within Product "Options".

You should then be able to do something like this:

```
using((Model.Entities context = new Model.Entities())
{
    var options = context.Products
        .Single(p => p.ID == 1)
        .Options
        .ToList();
}
```

to solve your problem.

Comment: and if there's no product with ID ==1 ?

Comment: Thanks. I generated the model from a prior database. Any tips on how to hide the mappings table?

Comment: If you have only productId and ProductOptionsId, it's "automatic", with the Poco generator for edmx. If you have other fields in your "relation" table, you'll have to remove them (but... if they're here, that's because you need them, no ?)

Comment: These are the only field I have in the relationship table. When doing code or model first EF it normally does what your mentioning. But not when generating from the DB.

Comment: Actually, I've just figured this out. My mappings table had it's own ID also. I should create the mappings table with two fields, with both as the primary key.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus If there is no product with ID == 1 it'll explode, I assumed this was okay due to the use of .First() in the example - I thought .Single() was a better fit that .First() so I changed it. But you are quite right to point it out ;)

Comment: @Grantunwin Yeah, just have to two Id columns and you should be good :)